# Using ggmap with inset_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a satellite image that I am trying to overlay onto a google map. My code is as follows:

```
img <- readPNG("satellite_image.PNG")
```

// The satellite image is orthorectified and has the mercator projection
// and georeferences perfectly with ArcGIS

```
map <- get_map(location=image_centroid, source="google", maptype="hybrid", zoom=15)

ggmap(map)  + inset_raster(img,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)
```

The problem is that the image does not line up with the google maps image. It is too small even at any zoom level. The correct polygon boundary is outlined in red and you can see that the image overlay is too small.

The xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax are the boundary box lat/lons for the correct polygon, not the image, so that isn't the problem I believe.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the img somewhere as a geotiff? Can you load it into R and check the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax and try to insert these values instead?
I actually believe that the values you provided are wrong. But I am just guessing here, because I dont have your raster or your shape/bounding box.

Comment: No geotiff. Just a PNG.  I think you may be right. I determined that the PNG file has a transparent border and the entire image (with the border) is being squeezed into the correct polygonal boundary space, effectively, shrinking my image. I know raster::crop and raster::mask exist but they require spatial attributes which PNG files do not have. 

How can I crop a PNG file to a spatial polygonal boundary? Do I need to convert lat/lon to screen coordinates? Yuk!

Comment: I think you have an artefact/border on the upper part of the img. You should be able to crop it with paint or photoshop. I know its not a clean programatical solution, but it might do the trick

Comment: Yes, thank you. Though I need to automate the process because the number of images is more than 1000. Does anyone know of a way to crop a PNG according to a spatial polygon boundary?

Comment: @JPlatt how did you get the legend to the bottom of this plot?

Comment: I added the colorband legend at time of performing the vegetative index calculations against the raw satellite image in the IDL language. It happens before the R graphics layer but I think an equivalent function in R is colorbar.plot.

Comment: did you try this without the zoom?